# Local non maven jar is searching on maven server. Why?

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-install-plugin, mvn-repo

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project portal: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.learning:portal:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.myapp.Local-2017:jar:1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

In pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myapp.Local</groupId>
    <artifactId>Local-2017</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Plugins:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>clean</phase>
                <configuration>
            <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                <groupId>com.myapp.Local</groupId>
                <artifactId>Local-2017</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
                <file>${basedir}/lib/Local.jar</file>
                <generatePom>true</generatePom>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared a Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.myapp.Local</groupId>
  <artifactId>Local-2017</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If Maven does not find it in your local repository, it will try to download it from outside. If you do not have a `settings.xml` it will try MavenCentral.

Comment: In eclipse it works fine but when i use "mvn clean install -U" command on server it gives this error

Comment: The question is: Where does artifact lie? It looks like a project of yours that you need to build beforehand.

Comment: it's build error, artifact lies with in the project

Comment: When you use Maven, you do not use artifacts in the project. You draw them from the local repository or a remote repository. Maven does not work that way.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that part of the problem is that you have put the execution of "maven-install-plugin" into the "clean" phase.  According to the [Maven 3.5 Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.2/maven-core/lifecycles.html), the "clean" phase is part of the "clean" life-cycle; i.e. gets run when you run "mvn clean".

I think it should be in the "default" lifecycle, probably the "validate" or "initialize" phase.  Note that dependency resolution typically occurs in a later phase.  It happens in the first phase that uses a plugin that requires dependency resolution as a prerequisite.  Put the "install-file" goal into an earlier phase in the lifecycle.